# How do I return a cell value if it falls within two date ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some locations and dates on the following spreadsheet:

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12flNuVzYWvKqkFNhpRauIOVkZEOuINK0peYJ3jYyDxw/edit?usp=sharing)

Currently the formula in cell `E1` returns the location (`Col E`) for the current event in relation to the start date (`Col F`).  However presently it does not take into account the *End Date* (`Col G`).

[image: Screenshot of the current sheet highlighting the problem]

As can be seen in the attached image - the *End Date* has been passed, yet **Sweden** is still being listed as the active location.

What I would like for the formula to do is return "No Event" if the current date is outside the active dates listed.

IE - From now until 03-06-20 it should return "No Event" and then from 04-06-20 to 26-07-20 it should return "Montreal" et al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula seems awfully complicated to me, but i'm not entirely sure I understand what you need.

Here is the formula I would use:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(E3:E,F3:F<=C2,G3:G>=C2),"No Event")
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Matt!!  Thank you for being super helpful.  I can't believe I managed to make such a simple formula so complex LOL   Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following (potential) solution.  I don't know whether it is the most efficient way to write this formula, and would appreciate feedback on it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($C$2=MEDIAN($C$2,
TO_DATE(MAX(IF($F3:$F7<C2,$F3:$F7))),
TO_DATE(MAX(IF($F3:$F7<C2,$G3:$G7)))),

VLOOKUP(ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(MAX(IF($F3:$F7<C2,$F3:$F7)))),{$F3:$F7,$E3:$E7},2,FALSE),
"No Event"))
```